# Create a launcher icon for PS3 media server

Tags: 12.04, media

Hi I was wondering how I could create a shortcut for PS3 media server on my unity dash instead of having to load PMS.sh every time I want to load the app.Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foud that installing the version here http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13046 installs the program as a system utility allowing a icon to be locked to the launcher.